# Save image from .php extension

Tags: php, image, curl

I am learning to work with curl php. I recently saw an image on Facebook that has the extension "*.php" and I tried to save it: in manually this image as loaded as "*.png". Than I tried to use curl for it

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36');

    $image = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

I received only

```
string(68) "�PNG  IHDR�IDATx�cd`0��/IEND�B`�"
```

When I saves it locally I see incorrect image with one pixel.
How can I upload the correct image?

Comment: That's the raw image data (though seems small). I'm unsure what you're actually trying to do? Save it to a file? In which case you can write that raw data to a file.

Comment: @Jonnix yeah, I tried to save it to a file with command: **file_get_contents** but I received an image with one pixel - it incorrect. So, I think that curl is not receiving full image data. I tried **file_put_contents** - the same..

Comment: Given it's a PHP extension, there is potentially some logic in there that's stopping you from downloading the image because it sees the call as automated, or maybe requires a cookie to be present or something else. Can't tell. Can you tell us the image URL that's failing?

Comment: @Jonnix > "Can you tell us the image URL that's failing? "  - Yes, look pls on the code curl where places url option, it's there

Comment: Just tested your exact code with a `file_put_contents('test.png', $image);` at the end and it works fine for me.

Comment: @Jonnix thanks! I see it now! just this code was implemented in other script, the seems that there is an error. thanks)